# Spark and huge shared objects

Tags: java, apache-spark

Can I have a shared object between executors on the same worker?

For example, I have some data in files. This data should be compiled before I can use it. After compilation it is not-serializable Java object. 
But unfortunately compilation takes a lot of time. I want to compile it once on each worker and use this object in all tasks on the worker.

Could you give me some advice how I can achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Broadcast variables would be a potential answer, though the not serializable part would still be an issue.  Another potential idea is to use mapPartitions.  This will apply a function over a partition as opposed to each record.

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(...)
rdd.repartition(numExecutors).mapPartitions( iter => {
    val yourObject = new ExpensiveObject()
    iter.map(records => yourFunction(records, yourObject))
    })
```

This would create the object once per executor, and then you could use it.  Unfortunately if your application requires multiple passes, you'd have to rebuild it for each pass.

Comment: Thanks, for your answer. I have already use mapPartition, I don't like it, because I get 35 partitions RDD from cassandra by default, but have only 6 workers. I don't want to use re-partition to 6, because it is not efficient approach. Now I try to mix mapPartition and use static method with some cache mechanism.